# ToolStripMenuItem double click?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program with a MenuStrip, containing multiple ToolStripMenuItems. There are 4 main ones, and each of those has a collection of more ToolStripMenuItems which appear as a dropdown from the main items.

I'm attempting to force the user to double click the items (this program is run on a small touch screen device and the users are accidentally pressing the wrong items by mistake...when a drop down menu appears by clicking the upper level menu, the first menu item is partially over the top level menu item, causing it to be highlighted if they hold their finger a minute too long and then "clicking" it when they lift their finger). I changed the Click event that was being fired from these items to the DoubleClick event, and changed the DoubleClick property of each ToolStripMenuItem to true, but the first click on any of the menu items causes the drop down menu to collapse instead of allowing me to physically double click the menu item.

I've been looking through the MSDN documentation but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this one out. Below is a simple example.

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.DoubleClick
    Me.Close
End Sub
```

It's not firing the event because it's not allowing me to double click the menu item in the first place(from what it looks like, anyway).

Comment: If you are not sure if it's even firing the event, you could put a debug message within that sub (like just before Me.Close) to find out for sure. That will help determine where the issue is.

Comment: Should have clarified...I do have code in the double click event (shown above). I set a breakpoint on the `Me.Close` line which isn't being hit, and it isn't closing the form anyway as it should. All of my ToolStripMenuItems are set up in this way, the one shown above was the simplest example of it.

Comment: That's not practical, the method that ensures the dropdown automatically closes, ToolStripMenuItem.OnMouseButtonStateChange(), is private and cannot be overridden.  You can technically override OnMouseDown/Up() but you'll have a very hard time reliably resetting the click counter.  Just make it usable, give the menu items a large font so they are easy to poke with a thumb.

Comment: I know it isn't practical, but it is needed for this application. The true issue is that the screen is very sensitive and they are hitting the wrong button. They click the top menu option to get the dropdown, and the dropdown menu positions itself in such a way to fit on the screen that the first option becomes highlighted and fires the click event if they hold their finger down a second too long. Forcing them to double click would remove the accidental button pushes altogether